# Objects going out of border with flex property

Tags: html, css

Using css `flex` property, the element stick together either and go out of the border. I have tried using `justify-content: space-around;` but it made things just worse. I have given the property to the parent element with a class called `cards-main` and it also is in another element with an id `main`.
(Note: in the code attached there is just one element so that the question won't  get closed.).

```css
.car{
    position: relative;
    height: 385px;
    width: 220px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border-radius: 10%;
}

#cards_main{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    width: 3;
    height: max-content;
    margin-left: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="cards_main">
        <div class="car">
            <img src="..."
                alt="">
            <h3>Helios</h3>
            <hr>
            <h5 class="text_desc">Price: $2000</h5>
            <h5 class="text_desc">Conditon: New</h5>
            <h5 class="text_desc ">Phone number: 050-367-81-21</h5>
            <button class="glow-on-hover">Add </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "the element stick together either and go out of the border", could you describe it a little more?

Comment: `width: 3;` is an issue here, it has no value

Comment: @AriSeyhun they go in a row either vertically or horizontally(depending on flex direction). They are not distributed over the container.

Comment: You would like the elements to be in a single horizontal row?

Comment: I would like them to be distributed evenly

Comment: If you mean that the image is going out of border use (  width="100%" ) to fit it in the Div.

Comment: Ok I will use that

Answer (score 1):

Add a style for your image inside car class to make the image responsive.

```
.car img{
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My goal was achieved after using the flex-wrap: wrap; property.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).